# Can you concatenate an if statement without using a ternary?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to concatenate an if statement like so:

```
policeRecord = "Hi" + (if (x < crimes.length) {", ";});
```

I know that you can do it using a ternary:

```
policeRecord = "Hi" + ((x < crimes.length) ? ", " : "");
```

But can you do it with a full if statement?

Comment: The difference here is that the ternary operator results in a value.  Essentially it _returns_ something.  An `if` block is just a block of code, there's no resulting value.

Comment: You could wrap the if statement inside of a function: `policeRecord = "Hi" + (function() { if(x < crimes.length) { return ", "; } }());`, but that defeats the purpose of the ternary operator.

Comment: If you want to make your code less readable you can do `"Hi" + ((x < crimes.length || '') && ', ')` as well. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yk9gA/)

Comment: For fun, here is another obscure way: `"Hi" + ['',', '][x < crimes.length]`

Comment: @FelixKling That way is actually readable! That's what I call real fun!

Comment: @bfavaretto: Actually it does not work :-/ You need to coerce the boolean value into a number explicitly: `"Hi" + ['',', '][+(x < crimes.length)]`

Comment: Ah ok, so you guys are saying that an if statement itself doesn't do anything. At the very least you need a function to execute so that it returns something. Is that correct?

So the function works as an operator?

I wrapped it in a (function () {if else})(); and it worked. Thanks all.

Comment: @Korey A function (as I suggested in my answer) works because it returns a value, while an `if` statement does not. The ternary operator works because it's always used in an expression, and expressions do return a value.

Comment: @FelixKling I thought I could avoid that by overriding `Boolean.prototype.toString`, but no. Damn "[abstract operation ToString](http://es5.github.com/#x9.8)"! (Seriously now, I'm glad the specification doesn't let us do that.)

Answer (score 3):

`if` is a **statement**. Statements cannot be used as part of an **expression**.

Typically expressions consist of operators and sub-expressions and create values. Statements don't belong in any of these categories, they are not expressions and not operators.

For more technical information, have a look at the ECMAScript specification: http://es5.github.com/.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is invalid JavaScript syntax so you cannot do it.

I'm not sure why you would want to do it either because I actually thing it causes a loss of clarity (there's a lot of jumble of symbols there).

If you wanted to do some sort of fancy one-liner to confuse people without using the ternary operator, you could do array/string manipulation based on element length:

```
policeRecord = "Hi" + (new Array(+(x < crimes.length) + 1)).join(', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

`if` is a **statement** and doesn't return a value, whereas `?` is an **operator**.

In the case of `function` it's notable, that there is a function statement and a function operator, so you can do

```
function () { }  // function statement
```

and you can also do

```
var fn = function () { };  // function operator
```

Short answer: You can't replace or interchange if and ?. You *may* create a function that does it, but running through a function has not the performance of native expressions.

Comment: It's interesting that the ECMAScript specification does not list function definitions as statements (they have their own section). In fact, it explicitly points out that function declarations treated as statements can lead to problems: http://es5.github.com/#x12. Seems like functions are something special.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, javaScript is interesting, except of the specs ;) Probably because it's treated as a literal, like { } for anonymous objects?

Comment: I honestly don't know... as *function expression*, probably. But function declarations are ... I don't know what they are :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a function *à la* SQL's `COALESCE` (but checking for `true` instead of `NULL`):

```
function iftrue(checkThis, returnIfTrue, returnIfFalse) {
    if(checkThis) {
        return returnIfTrue;
    }
    return returnIfFalse;
}
policeRecord = "Hi" + iftrue(1 < crimes.length, ", ", "");
```

Not sure how much better that would be, though.